# Constructor on type: "Namespace.type" not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I am using Castle.Windsor as an IOC.

So I am trying to resolve a service type in the constructor of an HTTPHandler. I keep receiving this error, "**Constructor on type: "Namespace.type" not found.**" My configuration has the following entries for service type: IDocumentDirectory

```
<component id="restricted.content.directory" service="org.myorg.foundations.services.content.IDocumentDirectory, org.myorg.foundations.services" type="org.myorg.foundations.services.content.RestrictedLocalizationDocumentDirectory, org.myorg.foundations.services">
    <parameters>
      <contentDirectory>${content.directory}</contentDirectory>
      <localizations>
        <array>
          <item>en-us</item>
          <item>es-us</item>
        </array>
      </localizations>
    </parameters>
  </component>

  <component id="content.directory" service="org.myorg.foundations.services.content.IDocumentDirectory, org.myorg.foundations.services" type="org.myorg.foundations.services.web.client.WebServiceDocumentDirectory, org.myorg.foundations.services.web.client">
    <parameters>
      <webServiceURL>#{contentDirectoryWebsiteUrl}</webServiceURL>
    </parameters>
  </component>
```

In my new handler the constructor looks like this:

```
 public HeartBeatHttpHandler(IDocumentDirectory contentDirectory)
    {
        _contentDirectory = contentDirectory;
    }
```

I have never recieved this error using Castle.Windsor. Can someone explain?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the implementation of `IDocumentDirectory` provide?

Comment: is HeartBeatHttpHandler instance retrieved with windsor too ? if so, could you show the windsor component configuration for HeartBeatHttpHandler

Comment: What are the real value of "Namespace.type" in your error message ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot inject a dependency into managed .NET HTTPHandler code. The objects that implement IHttpHandler **must have a parameter-less constructor**.

I used an application container instead. Which wouldn't have been my first choice.

-Nick