# .NET Custom Control (ToolStripControlHost) Wreaks Havoc on the Designer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to have a MaskedTextBox in a ToolStrip, which isn't included by default, so I followed some advice I found online, and created custom control that inherits from ToolStripControlHost. What I've created works great when I'm running the application, but it really messes up the designer. By "messes up", I mean the custom control (Along with some others) disappear from the ToolStrip. Also I can no longer add new controls to the ToolStrip, and I can't select the existing controls on the ToolStrip to edit them.

Here's my class.

```
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.ToolStrip | ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.StatusStrip)]
public partial class ToolStripMaskedTextBox : ToolStripControlHost
{
    public MaskedTextBox MaskedTextBox
    {
        get { return Control as MaskedTextBox; }
    }

    public ToolStripMaskedTextBox()
        : base(CreateControlInstance()) { }

    private static Control CreateControlInstance()
    {
        MaskedTextBox mtb = new MaskedTextBox();
        mtb.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        mtb.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 16);
        mtb.PasswordChar = '*';
        return mtb;
    }
}
```

Any help on what I might be doing wrong that's giving the designer a hard time would be appreciated.

**Addition Info**

Now when I open my class file in Visual Studio, I get a warning page with the following error:

```
Constructor on type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripControlHost' not found.
```

**Addition Info 2**

The problem only occurs after building the solution. I can get the designer working correctly by modifying the Form.Designer.cs file in even the smallest way. Like adding a single space. From there on out the designer will work fine. That is until I build the solution. Then the designer freezes up again. None of the controls on the form can be edited.

Comment: Rebuild the solution, restart VS, and see if that helps.

Comment: @SLaks - I've tied that, and sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't. The problem seems to be completely random.

Comment: Have a look at `*.Designer.cs` after you saved the form and look if it is serialized correctly.

Comment: @Olivier - Which designer file should I be looking at? The one for the form the control has been placed on? Is there something odd I should be looking for?

Comment: `MyForm.Designer.cs`. Check the `InitializeComponent` method of your form the control has been placed on.

Comment: @mellowsoon If your solution is currently set to Release mode, try setting it back to debug mode.

Comment: It might also be worth checking this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629090/vs-2008-designer-and-usercontrol

Comment: The posted code works fine in VS2008 .NET 3.5.  Can't reproduce any of those issues.  Do you have any events hooked up related to the `ToolStrip` itself besides the clicking events?  Try using your `ToolStrip` in an empty project, see if you can reproduce the problems there.

Comment: @Olivier - I don't see anything unusual in the designer file. What I found is when the designer is "stuck", modifying the designer file in any way (Even adding a single space) "unsticks" the designer. At least for a few builds. Then it gets stuck again.

Comment: @Kev Ritchie - I really hope the answer isn't "The designer is just dumb" haha

Comment: @mellowsoon :) - referring back to your configuration mode - are you set to release or debug?

Comment: @LarsTech - I gave that a try, and I'm unable to reproduce the problem. Even if I add all the same controls to the form in my empty project, the problem doesn't occure. Hrm...

Comment: @Kev Ritchie - I've tried it in both modes, and the results are the same.

Comment: See if [this link][1] helps. Scroll to bottom.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667491/constructor-on-type-namespace-type-not-found

Comment: @mellowsoon Any new update on this?

Answer (score 11):

According to the exception

```
Constructor on type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripControlHost' not found.
```

I found some information on the MSDN Forum.

This happends because the `ToolStripControlHost` class does not have a constructor with no parameter.

To solve this problem, you can create your own ToolStripControlHost with a none-parameter constructor and make the ToolStripMaskedTextBox inherited from your ToolStripControlHost. Try something like the following

```
//Declare a class that inherits from ToolStripControlHost.
[ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.ToolStrip | ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.StatusStrip)]
public class ToolStripMaskedTextBox : MyCustomToolStripControlHost
{
    // Call the base constructor passing in a MaskedTextBox instance.
    public ToolStripMaskedTextBox() : base(CreateControlInstance()) { }

    public MaskedTextBox MaskedTextBox
    {
        get
        {
            return Control as MaskedTextBox;
        }
    }


    private static Control CreateControlInstance()
    {
        MaskedTextBox mtb = new MaskedTextBox();
        mtb.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        mtb.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 16);
        mtb.PasswordChar = '*';
        return mtb;
    }
}

public class MyCustomToolStripControlHost : ToolStripControlHost
{
    public MyCustomToolStripControlHost()
        : base(new Control())
    {
    }
    public MyCustomToolStripControlHost(Control c)
        : base(c)
    {
    }
}
```

#### This will fix the problem with your exception.

The Problem with the Forms Designer (ToolStripMaskedTextBox is not visible after running the app) is not solved but you can close the designer and open the file again.

Then you can go on without any problems.

**Hope this helps**

Comment: This did solve the constructor problem, but unfortunately didn't solve the designer problem.

Comment: That looks like a bug, even on the msdn forum no one knows how to solve this. I tried so many things too

Comment: For me, the designer problem only occurred when the ToolStripMaskedTextBox control was located in the same project as the form I tried to use it on. When I put it into a separate project, the designer problem went away, without having to resort to using the System.Windows.Forms namespace as [Harry suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20334693/520044).

Answer (score 1):

I've used [dknaack's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8899286/126537), but placed `MyCustomToolStripControlHost` class in a separate file in System.Windows.Forms namespace. And...

First: it works - no exception.
Then: my control is visible in designer as well, so it's a jackpot.

Answer (score 0):

In [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667491/constructor-on-type-namespace-type-not-found), the answer was that the objects that implement "blah" interface must have a parameter-less constructor. Give it a try.

Comment: Thats what i said in my answer (parameterless-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: I also succeeded with dknaack's solution above, but only after I realized I was looking for the custom ToolStrip Control in the wrong place.  The custom control doesn't show up in the Toolbox itself.  Rather it shows up in the dropdown list of components under the "Add ToolStripButton" that appears on the ToolStrip when it is selected (in the designer).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution of designer's problem.
https://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/control/tschdesigneravail.html#tips_comment (Japanese)

All you need is just make a class derived from ToolStrip and substitute it.

```
class DesignerFriendlyToolStrip : ToolStrip { }

var ts = new DesignerFriendlyToolStrip();
ts.Items.Add(toolStripMaskedTextBox);
form.Controls.Add(ts);
```

I don't know why this is effective. Anyone knows...?